# Code from C# to Objective-C for Constructors

Tags: c#, objective-c, constructor

We have to convert our C# code to Objective-C code and i was having a hard time figuring out how to create one constructor with no arguments while the other with 2 arguments.
This is the C# code that I am trying to convert:

```
     namespace Account
{
class Program
{

    public class Account
    {

        private double balance;
        private int accountNumber;

        public Account()
        {
            balance = 0;
            accountNumber = 999;
        }

        public Account(int accNum, double bal)
        {
            balance = bal;
            accountNumber = accNum;
        }
        }
}
```

}

And this is what I have so far for the Objective C not sure if it is even correct or not

```
     @interface classname : Account 
   {
@private double balance;
@private int accountNumber;

@public Account()
   }
```

Open to any help i can get thank you very much, Danny

Answer (score 3):

you simply provide two initializers, which takes the general form:

```
@interface MONAccount : NSObject
@private
    double balance;
    int accountNumber;
}

/* declare default initializer */
- (id)init;

/* declare parameterized initializer */
- (id)initWithAccountNumber:(int)inAccountNumber balance:(int)inBalance;

@end

@implementation MONAccount

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    /* objc object allocations are zeroed. the default may suffice. */
    if (nil != self) {
        balance = 0;
        accountNumber = 999;
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithAccountNumber:(int)inAccountNumber balance:(int)inBalance
{
    self = [super init];
    if (nil != self) {
        balance = inBalance;
        accountNumber = inAccountNumber;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Objective C is a bit different from other languages.  It has a weirder syntax compared to other languages.  Though from what I've seen, it appears that you haven't learnt much about objective-c yet.  I would recommend you look at apple's documentation or get a book to actually learn about how the objective-c syntax works.  It shouldn't take too long to learn the syntax, but here's how you should do it.

```
@interface NSObject : Account
{
@private
double balance;
int accountNumber;
}
-(void)account; //No Arguements
-(void)account:(int)accNum withBalance:(double)bal; //2 Arguements

@implementation Program

-(void)account
{
balance = 0;
accountNumber = 999;
}

-(void)account:(int)accNum withBalance:(double)bal
{
balance = bal;
accountNumber = accNum;

}
```